# Apache - Loading is very slow after inactivity. Most states of connections are in K - KeepAlive

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, php7, slow-connection, keepalive

I enabled the apache status module, and saw that most of the connections on the apache scoreboard are showing a "K" value.

On my server, when I enable KeepAlive, during inactivity it takes a while to access the pages, then it gets fast.

I checked the DNS resolution time is ok.

Could anyone tell me what was wrong?

Scoreboard Apache:

```
._RC.KCKKRKRKRRKKK_KWKKKCKK.CR.KKKW_C_CKKKKKKKKKKKRK___CKRK_KK_K
CKKKK_K_KWKKKKK_KRRR_KK_KKKK.KR.KKK._K_K_CKKKK.R.K__KKR.KC._KR_R
KKKK............................................................
........
```

Comment: you are probably using prefork mpm model, a small number of workers and mod_php, am I right? Also, mod_status provides a list of requests, check them to see which requests are keeping all those connections alive, note that you can limit the number of keepalives sent also.

Answer (score 0):

My mpm_prefork.conf

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers        5
    MinSpareServers     5
    MaxSpareServers     40
    MaxRequestWorkers   200
    MaxConnectionsPerChild  1000
</IfModule>
```

I believe it is nothing with the application. When I disable keepalive, no request is on hold, everything works very well, but when I enable it, it starts to experience a slow problem on the first connection.

Comment: You posted this as a solution, but I don't understand which part of this is the solution?